# How to get creation scripts on SQL Server - Automated (DDL Events, Power Shell)

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, ddl

I'm facing an issue on getting the creation scripts for all objects from the Data Base. we want to get it to save as initial versioning (like the first version of everything), the idea for that is if we alter something or it goes wrong somehow, we have the previous objects scripts and can apply rollback. We also using DDLEvents to get all the historic of modifications and so on...

I could get part of the solution with Object_Definition(), but unfortunatelly this is limited and I can't get any result for Tables Definition... And I need everything that is created with the table scripts (contraints, indexes and so on), exactly like when we get it manually on SQL Server Management Studio

I found some Power Shell Scripts and been trying to get part to part what I need:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$logFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\SQL\Table Scripts\Scripts_DBTables.sql"

$DB = "DBTables"

# Create an SMO connection to the instance
$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "Server"  

$dbs=$s.Databases 

# Obj to use scripter()
$scrp = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($s) 

# scripter() obj Options Property
$scrp.Options.AppendToFile = $True 
$scrp.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True 
$scrp.Options.DriAll = $True 
$scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = $false 
$scrp.Options.IncludeHeaders = $True 
$scrp.Options.ToFileOnly = $True 
$scrp.Options.Indexes = $True 
$scrp.Options.WithDependencies = $True 

$scrp.Options.FileName = $logFile

#$scrp.Script($dbs["$DB"].Tables) 

foreach($item in $dbs["$DB"].Tables)
{
 $tablearray+=@($item)
}

$scrp.Script($tablearray)
```

With this I can get part of what I need which is the creation table scripts, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, 
Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried to find the dll which would match with the code below, but I only could find the Version=16.100.0.0 in the folder of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE.

Is there someone that have done this kind of work before or have any ideas what could be done to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What are you *actually* asking here? The only question you ask is if someone has experience (to which the answer is yes or no). What is the real question you want to ask?

Comment: I want to know if someone has any idea of how to do that, or have done it before! If so, how was done like: SQL, Any Programing language, Power Shell or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The [**dbatools**](https://dbatools.io/download/) third-party module can generate scripts very easily. You can pass most of its objects to [`Export-DbaScript`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Export-DbaScript) and you will get a script for that object.

```
Get-DbaDbTable -SqlInstance DEV01 -Database Test1  | Export-DbaScript
```

To load the module, use

```
Install-Module dbatools
```

Or

```
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser
```

---

To monitor for changes, you may want to consider either SQL Audit, or some other third-party tool, for example Redgate SQL Compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Defo gonna give it a shot to dbatools! How about monitoring changes, we adopted DDLEvents, the trigger capture every changes made and save it into a table for each DB.